# Setting up a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on an app that uses ES 6 JavaScript. This app has a list of games. Each game has an ID. The objects are defined like this:

```
let game1 = { id:'XVF/328', name:'Checkers', publisher:'ABC games' };
let game2 = { id:'FTY/294', name:'Chess', publisher:'Infinity Fun' };
let game3 = { id:'QPG/72Z', name:'Backgammon', publisher:'Max Fun' };
```

I have an array that looks like this:

```
let games = [];
```

I'm trying to understand how to populate this array for fast access. I no that I'll get an ID, like 'FTY/294'. I'm trying to understand how to setup the games array so that I can do something like:

```
let selectedGame = games['FTY/294'].
```

How can you do this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of ways to populate an array.  Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @whipdancer actually there aren't ways to get array in this case, only object. using `key` `value` pairs

Comment: Actually, the question is about how to populate an array.  As the answers below demonstrate, there are a number of ways to do accomplish that.  His intended purpose makes a difference.

Comment: @whipdancer All those answers populating object instead of array, and authors mentioned that

Comment: @The Which is exactly my point.  His intended purpose makes a difference.  They assume (correctly IMO) that an object would better serve OP's need.  I simply asked for clarification on OP's need.

Comment: @whipdancer ok, probably i misunderstood you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript, objects behave much like `HashTable` or `Dictionary` in Java/C#. You use store values under a key, and use that key to later retrieve the value.

If you use an object rather than an array then you get key->value access.

```
let games = {};
games['XVF/328'] = { id:'XVF/328', name:'Checkers', publisher:'ABC games' };
games['FTY/294'] = { id:'FTY/294', name:'Chess', publisher:'Infinity Fun' };
```

If you need to iterate over all the games you can use `Object.keys(games)` to retrieve a list of all keys, and then use that to iterate your object.

```
Object.keys(games).forEach(x => {
   var game = games[x];
   // do something with game
});
```

In ES6 you also have the option of using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which gives you the benefits of an associative array (as used above) but with the addition of iterable support.

```
var games = new Map();
games.set('XVF/328', { id:'XVF/328', name:'Checkers', publisher:'ABC games' });
// ....etc

for (let [id, game] of games) {
    // do something with the game
}
```

Comment: Instead of `let games = {};`, I recommend `let games = Object.create(null)`

Comment: @laruiss `Object.prototype` method will be skipped when you create a new object as you describe

Comment: That's a great trick, didn't realize that `{}` inherited from Object.prototype, whereas `Object.create(null)` does not. On the plus side you can then iterate without using `hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: if you are using `Object.key` you dont need care about `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @The You do not, that's why I used it. I was highlighting that you don't need to use `hasOwnProperty` when using `Object.create(null)` in a `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider [using an object as an associative array](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/) for this, which functions similar to a dictionary (i.e. you pass in a key and you receive a value in return) :

```
// Define your object
let games = {};
// Add each game here
games['XVF/328'] = { name:'Checkers', publisher:'ABC games' };
games['FTY/294'] = { name:'Chess', publisher:'Infinity Fun' };
games['QPG/72Z'] = { name:'Backgammon', publisher:'Max Fun' };
```

And then simply retrieve the game you are looking for via :

```
let selectedGame = games[id]; // where id is something like "XVF/328"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ids as keys in new object :

```
games = {};

games[game1.id] = game1;
games[game2.id] = game2;
games[game3.id] = game3;
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
game1 = { id:'XVF/328', name:'Checkers', publisher:'ABC games' };
game2 = { id:'FTY/294', name:'Chess', publisher:'Infinity Fun' };
game3 = { id:'QPG/72Z', name:'Backgammon', publisher:'Max Fun' };

games = {};

games[game1.id] = game1;
games[game2.id] = game2;
games[game3.id] = game3;

console.log(games);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6, then you should definitely use [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
const games = new Map(); // or let
games.set('XVF/328', { id:'XVF/328', name:'Checkers', publisher:'ABC games' })
games.set('FTY/294', { id:'FTY/294', name:'Chess', publisher:'Infinity Fun' };
games.set('QPG/72Z', { id:'QPG/72Z', name:'Backgammon', publisher:'Max Fun' };

let game = games.get('FTY/294');
```